# How to enable ssl in NGINX using Goddady certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I am quite new on this, havent install SSL certificates in nginx yet so excuse my ignorance.

I have a certificate from godaddy's but i cant seem to find a way to use it on my linux server (ubuntu 18.04).

I will run through what I have done till now.

**Godaddy certificate**

In the process to create a SSL certificate first godaddy provides two files one with your SSL certificate key and another with the CSR (not sure what it is).

The you are prompted to download the SSL certificate which is another two files, one which is some sort of bundle and the other is something else *(from their website)Copy your SSL certificate file and the certificate bundle file to your Nginx server.* both this file is **.crt**

**Router**

I have enable any incoming 443 to redirect the traffic to my server.

**Server Ubuntu 18.04**

I followed their not so helpful tutorials.

https://uk.godaddy.com/help/nginx-install-a-certificate-6722

https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-ubuntu-for-nginx/

**Edited the nginx config file**

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myweb

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myweb.key;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certf.crt;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/b_certf.crt;

    root /media/world/myweb/origin;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 192.168.0.9 lmyweb.com www.myweb.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

When accessing my website, I get 404 *this site cant be reach*.

Am I missing something? maybe some enable in Nginx that I dont know about? or maybe im configuring the above in the wrong file?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with what a 404 error means?  It means that the page cannot be found.  Can you provide the output of `ls /media/world/myweb/origin`.  I bet there is no index.html, index.htm, or index.nginx-debian.html file available.  Is your browser showing a secure connection?  It seems that NGINX is working properly.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned. I also cant load the above nginx file config. when I try to load i get this error "Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
"

Comment: Another error also " no "ssl_certificate_key" is defined for certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/b_certf.crt" and the "ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:"

Comment: I checked the directory from origin, the index.html is there :)

Comment: Use `listen 443 ssl;` NOT `ssl on;` - `ssl on;` is considered deprecated and could go away **at any time** and should not be used.  Secondly, you need a **single certificate file** containing all the certs in the certification chain; you cannot have multiple ssl_certificate lines, it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thanks yep I kinda figured something is up with having multiples certificate. Godaddy's way of doing it, its very confusing so instead I went and installed certbot, works like a charm everything done :)

Comment: @LukeDS Yeah well certbot can be pain, but GoDaddy certs are better for wildcards or for extended validation certs.  Provided an answer anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're falling into quite a few pitfalls, as well as your SSL cert problems.

So let's go through this bit by bit.

---

**SSL Certificates for NGINX**

Unlike Apache, you can only provide a single `ssl_certificate` line in a server block; extra ones will cause problems or the thing to ignore certificates.

NGINX certificates need to contain the following in this order:

- Your site / `serer_name`'s  specific cert
- The CA certificates chain.  This is provided by GoDaddy along with your certs in their ZIP files.

You can usually do this by something like `cat sitecert.crt ca-cert.crt > sitecert.fullchain.pem`, then use the `sitecert.fullchain.pem` file in your NGINX configs.

---

**SSL Configuration**

NGINX configuration for SSL needs to be the following (note that other config bits are stripped out or replaced by `# ...` to indicate you need to configure bits at this point for whatever the rest of your config is):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/sitecert.fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/sitecert-private.key;

    # ... Site specific configs here
}
```

This fixes several things:

1. This uses the *proper* `listen 443 ssl;` line.  You should **not** be using `ssl on;` as this is considered old and deprecated.
2. This uses the full-chain of certificates and the key and has them in a sane order.

Comment: Thank you. I will try now to see if i get it working.